# How to use max function inside IN clause

Tags: mysql

I need to select max(time) and some some specific hours in single table. i tried something like this. any idea?

```
SELECT * FROM ara WHERE date = '2017-03-31' and time in('07:00:00','13:00:00','19:00:00',max(tme)) order by time desc

SELECT * FROM ara WHERE date = '2017-03-31' and (time = '07:00:00' or time = '13:00:00' or time = '19:00:00'or time = max(time)) order by time desc
```

Comment: Where are you taking that `max(tme)` from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're selecting the maximum time from that same `ara` table, you can do that this way

```
SELECT  *
FROM    ara
WHERE   date = '2017-03-31' and
        ( 
          time in ('07:00:00','13:00:00','19:00:00') OR
          time = (SELECT MAX(time) FROM ara)
        )
ORDER BY time desc
```

Comment: I can't get max of time i get only 07:00:00','13:00:00','19:00:00.

Comment: Add sample data and expected result to your question please

Comment: sorry my question was wrong i got exact what i want thank you.